# Removing items from a queue in Java

Tags: java

Let's say i have a queue of objects in Java like this:

```
Queue<Element> q = new LinkedList<>();
```

with Element being:

```
class Element {
     public int x;
     public  int y;
     public  String moves;

}
```

During my program i may put multiple Objects of type Element inside the queue from which many may have the same x AND y..So let's say my queue contains multiple (x=1,y=2) objects and i just find an object that has x=1 and y=2 and moreover better Element.moves than all of them.Is there a way to somehow locate and remove all these elements from the queue?

Comment: If you need random access, don't use a queue.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca What else could i use that implements FIFO but also has random access?

Comment: Please ask a new question about a FIFO structure with random access. Don't edit an existing question until answers don't match it anymore.

Comment: @Epitheoritis32 use an `ArrayList`. This gives you random access with `get()`. You can "simulate" FIFO by using `add()` to add to the end of the queue and `remove(0)` to pop from the head, which is how a FIFO operates.

Comment: @Epitheoritis32 regarding my previous comment, notice that you lose a bit of performance when removing the first element from the queue, as it is a O(n) operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to consider an alternative.

You can use an `ArrayList` which gives you random access with the `get()` method.

You can simulate a `Queue` by using the `add()` method to push to the end of the list and `remove(0)` to get and remove an element from the head.

This of course can be not-ideal in a couple of cases:

1. You actually need to instantiate a `Queue` because some other piece of code expects that. While `LinkedList`, as suggested by Lutz Horn, implements `Queue`, `ArrayList` doesn't.
2. Performance: `remove(0)` has O(n) time complexity because the underlying array needs to be shifted left every time you call `remove()`.

On the other hand, you get an advantage when using random access, since that is O(1).

To wrap it up, you have to put your engineer hat on and decide which set of tradeoffs you want to accept. Since only you can know how you will use this, only you can answer that question.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. [`java.util.Queue<E>`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Queue.html) does not support this.

**Edit:** But you already have a `LinkedList`. Why do you use only its `Queue` methods if you want to do random access? `LinkedList` implements both `List` and `Queue`, just keep it.

```java
LinkedList<Element> ll = new LinkedList<>();
```

Comment: `LinkedList` is not good for random access. Use `ArrayList` instead.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca No doubt about this. But it seems that the OP wants both `List` and `Queue` behaviour. `ArrayList` does not implement `Queue`.

Comment: It doesn't, but it can be simulated. Since you can't have both, if you don't need to implement `Queue` for syntactic reasons (that is, you actually need an instance of `Queue`), `ArrayList` gives you the best of both worlds (see my comment to the question itself).

Comment: Agreed. But since we don't know what the OP wants, we should not guess what is the better approach.

Comment: Your comments pushed me to do a bit of thinking and, indeed, using an ArrayList has its drawbacks as well (performance when popping). So yeah, we should not guess the best approach since only OP can evaluate the tradeoffs of each method.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over all values, and remove all elements with worse moves:

```
Element theNewKid; // the new element we put in

Iterator<Element> qIt = q.iterator();
while(qIt.hasNext()) {
  Element next = qIt.next();
  if ( next.x == theNewKid.x && next.y == theNewKid.y && next.moves.compare(theNewKid.moves) > 0)
      qIt.remove()
}

q.add(theNewKid);
```